# PostgreSQL indeterminate ordering of results

Tags: postgresql

When I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "spree_products".id FROM "spree_products"
INNER JOIN "spree_variants"
   ON "spree_variants"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id"
  AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = 't'
INNER JOIN "spree_prices"
   ON "spree_prices"."variant_id" = "spree_variants"."id"
INNER JOIN "spree_products_taxons"
   ON "spree_products_taxons"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" 
INNER JOIN "spree_taxons"
   ON "spree_taxons"."id" = "spree_products_taxons"."taxon_id"
WHERE "spree_taxons"."id" IN (13)
AND "spree_prices"."currency" = 'USD'
AND ("spree_products".deleted_at IS NULL
  or "spree_products".deleted_at >= '2013-08-30 06:23:45.881488')
AND ("spree_products".available_on <= '2013-08-30 06:23:45.881974')
AND (spree_prices.amount IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 12 OFFSET 36
```

I get some records returned in different offsets. For example, I see a record with `ID=53` in both `OFFSET 24` and `OFFSET 36`.

If I add an `ORDER BY spree_products.id` clause to this statement, it makes the order determinate and I never see the same record returned in different offsets.

Comment: Of course you need ORDER BY to make Postgresql give you the records back in a certain order. But returning the same ID in different "offsets" when you have specified DISTINCT would seem like a bug to me. Or do you mean that in different executions of the same query the same ID can be returned at different positions? There's only one solution to that: add that ORDER BY clause like you have to.

Comment: All those double-quotes are not necessary...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That's what Active Record puts in place.

Answer (score 9):

That's because the SQL standard doesn't require PostgreSQL to return rows in any particular order without an `ORDER BY` clause. It can return them however it feels like. See [the manual for `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html). In particular:

> If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

and

> When using LIMIT, it is a good idea to use an ORDER BY clause that constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get an unpredictable subset of the query's rows — you might be asking for the tenth through twentieth rows, but tenth through twentieth in what ordering? You don't know what ordering unless you specify ORDER BY.

This makes `LIMIT` and/or `OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY` unsafe in almost all cases. It's permitted in case you've forced the ordering in an inner query, as a bit of a performance hack, but it's rarely a good idea.

You must add an `ORDER BY` clause to make your statement deterministic.

In this case, with the `DISTINCT` there it's probably doing hash aggregation - which tends to return results in an inconsistent order from execution to execution. Even if you were doing an index scan that *usually* returns results in order, you cannot assume that it will unless you tell PostgreSQL you require the rows in a particular order.

This is closely related to people who ask how to select rows in the "natural" order of a table; tables and result sets don't *have* a natural order. They're sets not lists. If you want an ordering you must specify one on an operation by operation basis.